# Data annotations in .Net Core are only client side or they also validate server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I have read that people can remove javascript from browsers or something and the validations of client side stop working, which is important for us to have server side validation..

In .NET Core, we have data annotations, does this work for both server and client side or do we need to make a validation in server side?

Also, using `[Remote]` validation, is the same thing? I am using both of this, and I am not sure if i need to also make the validations on the `create()` action for example..

One more thing, does `ModelState.IsValid()` work with remote validation? Thanks for any help

Example:

```
public IActionResult VerifyCargo(string Descricao, int ID_Cargo)
{
    var validateName = ValidateName(Descricao);

    if (validateName != null)
    {
        return Json($"Description {Descricao} is already in use.");
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(true);
    }
}

public RH_Cargos ValidateName(string Descricao)
{
    return _context.RH_Cargos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Descricao == Descricao);
}
```

I have those functions and in model I have a `[remote]` annotation that calls that first one...

It works fine, but do I need to make any validation on the `Create` action? Or will this `remote` attribute do for both server/client side? Is it safe?

Comment: They tend to work on the server side. (IE ModelState.IsValid) Client-side is just an implementation of Jquery validate

Comment: This means i dont need to do any validation on server side, for example, i did not make a field unique in database... And i made a remote validation where i return true or javascript error if exists that record, i dont need to do more validations in the create action, is that correct?

Comment: If you want validation than use XML format instead of json where you can validate against a schema.

Comment: I already did all my validations... And everything is working fine, i really don´t want to lose much more time on them, i just wanted to know if it is safe to leave it as they are or if i need to do any server side implementation... (i will update question for a brief example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In .NET Core, we have data annotations, does this work for both server and client side or do we need to make a validation in server side?

Those data annotations, i.e., `[Required]`, would work on the server. As others might have already mentioned, the client-side validation is a bonus/nicety added **only** when you include [jQuery Unobtrusive Validation](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive) and [jQuery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin (of course their dependency [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is also needed).

So don't need to worry if someone turns off JavaScript on the browser. You will still get the server-side validation by the MVC framework when the data posts back to the server.

That would also mean client-side validation cannot trusted. You can see it would be easy for others to by-pass the client-side validation and submit data to the server (i.e., using 3rd party tool like Postman).

> Also, using [Remote] validation, is the same thing?

The `[Remote]` attribute will call a method defined on the server to determine whether the field is valid or not. For that to work, you need to define an action method that returns a JSON response. Anything other than `true` would mean invalid input.

> I am not sure if i need to also make the validations on the create() action for example.

You would need to inspect `ModelState.IsValid` and make decisions what to do when there are errors. If you meant something other than checking the modal state, then I have no idea what you meant by making the validations.

> Does `ModelState.IsValid()` work with remote validation?

I am not sure what you meant by that. The remote validation requires an action method defined, which either returns `true` to indicate the input is valid, `false`, `undefind` or `null` to indicate the input is not valid, or returns a string for the error message.

`ModelState` does get updated after the remote validation returns.

**My rule of thumb**

I just never trust client inputs. Even you have all the validations setup, you still need to have your domain validations in place, to make sure everything is in valid state when the information persists.

One example I can think of could be: you have a form to take user's email and create an account. The field Email uses remote validation to check if the email has been taken or not. If it just happens that right after the remote validation comes back as OK, another person just quickly registers an account with the same email before the person submits the form. Now you can't just blindly create another account with the same email address because that email has been taken.

Comment: I disabled my javascript and i was able to insert a repeated record, the [Remote] validation did not work... That was my question, i actually needed to place a validation before creating a new record to verify if it was all ok in the server side again. 
But this was a great response, and i was able to clear up my doubts about data annotations. Thanks for the reply